# bash script which adds/removes comment tags to a html file based on file presence in folder

Tags: html, bash, sed

I've written a bash script which I want to check a folder for a list of files, and if the file is not present in the folder, it adds comment tags around the 'img' tags in the html file. The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the list of file names to match
FILE_LIST=("2375.jpg" "375_.jpg" "875.jpg")

# Define the path to the HTML file
HTML_FILE="./test.html"

# Loop over the file list
for FILE in "${FILE_LIST[@]}"; do
    # Check if the file exists in the folder
    if [ ! -f "$FILE" ]; then
        # File is missing, search for the line containing the file name in the HTML file and comment it out
        sed -i "/<img.*src=\"\.\/$FILE\".*>/ s/^/<!-- /; /<img.*src=\"\.\/$FILE\".*>/ s/$/ -->/" "$HTML_FILE"
    else
        # File exists, search for the line containing the file name in the HTML file and uncomment it if it's currently commented out
        sed -i "/<img.*src=\"\.\/$FILE\".*>/ s/<!--\(.*\)-->/\1/" "$HTML_FILE"
    fi
done
```

But this is adding multiple comment tags to some lines, and not adding them to others...

The sample html file with the lines I want to remove looks like this:

```
<img src="./3723.jpg" class="Fire" border="1" id="map15" onclick="showGraph(this);return true;">
<img src="./775.jpg" class="Fire" border="1" id="map16" onclick="showGraph(this);return true;">
<!--<img src="./575.jpg" class="Fire" border="1" id="map17" onclick="showGraph(this);return true;">-->
```

I think I'm close to fixing it but I have hit a wall!

Comment: 1. `sed` is probably not the best tool for this. 2. Since you are not using ERE (`-E` option), you misplaced escapement for `.`. Should be something like `<img\.*src=\".\/$FILE\"\.*>` and so on.

Comment: What would you suggest instead of `sed`?

Comment: Something what will understand structure of html and could work with comments in it, my personal choice would be python+beautifulsoup.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, `sed` would work if you allow for pretty heavy assumptions, like every `img` tag has own line, every comment with `img` has this `img` only and so on. Additionally, if it's your utility for own use, and you fully control input - it probably would be easiest.

Comment: Is PHP an option here?  That is what it was created for, it could build your html file on the fly, according to what files are available in the directory.